# Neo Keyboard-Layout Layer4: Fix Space instead of 0 when pressing AltGr

Tags: linux, linux-mint, keyboard-layout, modifier-keys

On `Linux Mint 20` the [neo keyboard layout](https://www.neo-layout.org/) has multiple layers.

Pressing <kbd>AltGr</kbd> will act as <kbd>Mod4</kbd> and swtich the layout to `layer 4`.
In this layer, pressing the <kbd>spacebar</kbd> would normally result in a press of <kbd>0</kbd>.
Somehow this does not happen, while it works for other numbers like <kbd>AltGr</kbd><kbd>m</kbd> --> <kbd>1</kbd>

Any suggestions on how to fix this misbehaviour?

Answer (score 0):

1. In the start menu, search for `keyboard` to open the related utility.
2. Select the neo layout via `German (Neo 2)` and edit its options via `Options...`
3. Select drop down menu `Switching to another layout`
4. Deselect the checkbox `Win+Space`
5. Click `Close`

Done